# Disable media Formatter in one action and return simple text

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How we can Bypass or Disable MediaFormatters(JSONFormatter is my only formatter) in some Actions of Choice?

```
    public string GetSample()
    {
        ...

        return "data1,data2,data3";
    }
```

In Above action for example, I dont actually need JsonFormatter to work.

I Found That **HttpResponseMessage** or**IHttpActionResult** let us control response text.
But I dont know If these classes can bypass MediaFormaters or not. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to force web api to return plain text, without any content-negotiation(formatting the output using json,xml,...)we can do this

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetSample()
{
    string result = "data1,data2,data3";
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response .Content = new StringContent(result, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
    return response ;
}
```

This is useful to improve performance because JsonFormatter is not so performant.